# how to prevent PageView.builder building page I didnt enter yet or delete getxcontroller after I leave the page - flutter/GetXcontroller

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

sorry in advance if i didnt describe my question clearly:

I have several pages made by `PageView.builder`, while swiping these pages on main screen left and right, I found their `initState` is already working, and GetXController inside are also loading their data. I use `Get.delete<Controller>` while clicking back button and coming back to main screen to remove these data.

However, the state and data will bring back to main screen if I didnt activate `Get.delete<Controller>`, and therefore next time I come to this page, the state of page will be not default, for instance the button still keep pressed status.

So my question is how to prevent page.builder to build the widget before I come inside to this page, or how to delete getxcontroller if I am not in this page. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the GetX by calling
`Get.reset();` --> this will re-initialize controllers

**Alternatively calling**

`Get.put(ControllerName());` in a build method will re-initialize the controller

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your comment, it indeed solve my problem!

Comment: Where should i call Get.reset() exactly?